# Android: Update SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to keep a counter of the times my application is lauched. To do that, I need to keep information stored in the device, even once the application has been killed.

I read this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

And I thought the easiest way to implement this, would be using SharedPreferences. So I wrote this code:

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int TimesLaunched = settings.getInt("TimesLaunched", 0);

TimesLaunched++;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("TimesLaunched", TimesLaunched);


editor.commit();
```

I found out it works the first time, so it chages from 0 to 1, but that is all. The following times I launched the app nothing happened.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: nothing happned?? no error?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Nothing, but I think I have solved. I didn't add this before the method: @SuppressLint("NewApi")

Comment: I have tried running your code and my TimesLaunched keeps getting updated.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120830214803/http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1):

I'm new with SharedPreferences, but at least I found what wasn't working in my particular case. I was forgetting to add @SuppressLint("NewApi") before the method, and since the level of my API wasn't the correct one, editor.commit() wasn't launched.

Normally Eclipse warn me about this kind of situation, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your preferences this way:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```